# Content recommendation system without deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, graph, recommendation-engine

I am exploring the field of recommendation systems and all I can find are techniques utilizing deep learning. I would not like to work in the area of deep learning. Thus, are there other approaches to content recommendation systems other than deep learning? Or should I change the topic if I don't like deep learning? I would also like to work on graphs in the recommendation system but for content and not collaborative-based recommendations. Any resources are useful.

Answer (score 0):

Deep Learning architeture perform very well on many real time use cases, like your own problem recomendation saystem.

If you cited problems clearly, then i suggest some archetectecture, by default you go with "sequential based archetecture like LSTM, GRU and Transformer. [Netflix Recommender system](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-dive-into-netflixs-recommender-system-341806ae3b48)